# Python requests.put() is giving error: Invalid API call, Wrong method or URL

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I have been trying to do a put request via [BambooHR](https://www.bamboohr.com/api/documentation/time_off.php) api to **add a time off** request. But it gives 404 and the header gives "Invalid API call, Wrong method or URL"

I couldn't understand what's wrong with my code. Add a time off request from Bamboo HR documentation is `/api/gateway.php/{company}/v1/employees/{employee id}/time_off/request/` Sample: `PUT /api/gateway.php/test/v1/employees/1/time_off/request/`

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.bamboohr.com/api/gateway.php/johnsnowlabs/v1/employees/96/time_off/requests/?status=requested'
response1= requests.put(url, auth=('68d4165c9262fcf2302745a6d791b23dsfsd4107','John11')

print(response1.status_code)
```

it gives 404 and when `response1.headers` then the error message says `Invalid API call, Wrong method or URL`

I tried different combination of inputs in url but none seems to be working. However, all the GET requests are working, it's only the PUT one is not working.

Comment: Are you sure that it should be PUT and not POST?

Comment: @BigGerman the documentation says HTTP Method:PUT --> https://www.bamboohr.com/api/documentation/time_off.php

Comment: Okay, after looking at the documentation I think url should be `"'https://api.bamboohr.com/api/gateway.php/johnsnowlabs/v1/employees/96/time_off/request"` and then you need to send the data in xml format in the body of the request

Comment: Also I hope those aren't your real credentials that you posted in the code

Comment: @BigGerman thanks, passing XML in the body of request seems to be working fine!